# [KDB+/Q]: Reattach Windows console to a background running q process

Tags: windows, kdb, q-lang

Assuming there is `q` process running in the background after launching it with `system` command:

```
$ q
q) system "q -p 5000"
q) \\
$
```

How can I attach my Windows console (cmd or PowerShell) or terminal multiplexer (such as ConEmu) back to that process, so that I get:

```
q)
q)\p
5000i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar question here: [Windows equivalent for Linux "screen" or another alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058072/windows-equivalent-for-linux-screen-or-another-alternative)

The asker is looking for a windows version of the Linux screen command, which I think would be what you are looking for. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to  be a native solution but you should read through it and see if it sheds any light on the topic for you.

A workaround using IPC, connect to the process from a new q session using:

```
q)h:hopen `::5000;
```

Then pass the command through to get the information you need.

```
q)h"sum 10 20"
30
```

Here's a link to the kx IPC cookbook for more info on IPC:
http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/ipc/

Hopefully some of this is useful to you.